# Where might I find the Socratic dialogue on the mythical story of private property/homesteading?

Tags: plato, dialectic

I read a great story awhile back about a group of philosophers who approached Socrates with a question regarding the rights of private property and if a man could rightly own land on a world that belonged to the gods anyway. As I remember it, a myth was referenced about a god who wanted to build a home on earth but a man claimed ownership of the property by right of farming. The man then asked the god for payment and appealed to the other gods for justice.
A discussion was held amongst the gods in Olympus regarding the true ownership of the property and some consensus was reached. I have been looking through a bunch of books including most of Plato's to no avail. Does this ring a bell for anyone? Much appreciated!

Comment: This sounds very off. There are no Plato's dialogues where gods hold discussions. Plato was very much opposed to private property, and it is addressed in the Republic in a rather negative way. Lucian wrote [Dialogues of the Gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogues_of_the_Gods) parody, but there is nothing like that there. I doubt there is a Socratic dialogue of this sort, perhaps it was some kind of modern stylization.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Conifold . I think you're right. I may also be way off in my recollection of the story.